# Google Seach Console API authorization issue with service account

Tags: javascript, api, oauth-2.0, google-app-maker

I'm trying to fetch data from Google search console (GSC) through http request.

I'm using google app Maker with javascript.

For my purpose I'm using a service account, all the scopes are already set up for the account.

I've copied the code provided by @Morfinismo.

```
/*********** SERVICE ACCOUNT CONFIGURATION USING THE OAUTH LIBRARY ***********
** All of the values are obtained from the .json file that is downloaded at
** the time of the service account creation
** Ref: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount
** Ref: https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2
*/


var accessData = {
  "private_key" : "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----THE KEY-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email" : "searchconsolebot@project-id-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "user_email" : "user@domain.com" // Why do we need a user mail ?
};


var scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly"]; //GSC api scope
scopes = scopes.join(" "); //join all scopes into a space separated string

function getOAuthService(user) {
  console.log("je passe par getOAuthService");
  user = user || accessData.user_email;
  console.log("user: " + user);
  return OAuth2.createService("GSC_Service_Account")
    .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
    .setPrivateKey(accessData.private_key)
    .setIssuer(accessData.client_email)
    .setSubject(user)
    .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())
    .setCache(CacheService.getUserCache())
    .setParam('access_type', 'offline')
    .setScope(scopes);
}


function reset(user) {
  var service = getOAuthService(user);
  console.log("service: " + service);
  service.reset();
  return service;
}


function getToken(userEmail){
  var totoken = reset(userEmail).getAccessToken();
  console.log(totoken);
  return reset(userEmail).getAccessToken();
}


function getGCSUrlData(urlGiven){
  var token = getToken();
  if(token){
    var reqBody = {
      startDate: "2019-01-01",
      endDate: "2020-01-23"
    };
    var options = {
      method : 'POST',           
      headers : {
        Authorization : 'Bearer ' + token,
      },
      contentType: 'application/json',
      payload: JSON.stringify(reqBody),
      muteHttpExceptions: true,
    };
    var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/" + encodeURIComponent(urlGiven) + "/searchAnalytics/query";
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    console.log(response);
  }
}
```

Using the OAuth library seems really great but it does return me an error

```
Error: Access not granted or expired. at getToken (Service_Account_Config:46)
```

Also I noticed that `getToken()` method requires a param but when calling it we don't give any param is it normal ?
And why do we need a user_email since we are using a service account ?
Which email should I enter for the user_email then ?

I would really appreciate some help about this issue and any advice to understand this kind of issue.

Thanks a lot,
Jacky

Comment: Just tried on firefox and it works perfectly fine... Why doesn't it work on chrome ? Thanks

Comment: I've tried to check the link provided by google https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token but it doesn't seem to exist may this be the problem ?

Comment: It finally works after configuring my service account again !

Answer (score 0):

Integration with a service account is very easy when using the [OAuth2 Library for AppsScript](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2). Here are the steps:

1.) In a server side script add the following:

```
/*********** SERVICE ACCOUNT CONFIGURATION USING THE OAUTH LIBRARY ***********
** All of the values are obtained from the .json file that is downloaded at
** the time of the service account creation
** Ref: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount
** Ref: https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2
*/

var accessData= {
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "service-account825@08012018.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "user_email": "user@domain.com"
};

var scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly"]; //drive api scope
scopes = scopes.join(" "); //join all scopes into a space separated string

function getOAuthService(user) {
  user = user || accessData.user_email;
  return OAuth2.createService("Service Account")
    .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
    .setPrivateKey(accessData.private_key)
    .setIssuer(accessData.client_email)
    .setSubject(user)
    .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())
    .setCache(CacheService.getUserCache())
    .setParam('access_type', 'offline')
    .setScope(scopes);
}


function reset(user) {
  var service = getOAuthService(user);
  service.reset();
  return service;
}


function getToken(userEmail){
  return reset(userEmail).getAccessToken();
}
```

Then you can simplye call the service you need by doing the following:

```
function getGCSUrlData(urlGiven){
  var token = getToken();
  if(token){
    var reqBody = {
      startDate: "2020-01-01",
      endDate: "2020-01-23"
    };
    var options = {
      method : 'POST',           
      headers : {
        Authorization : 'Bearer ' + token,
      },
      contentType: 'application/json',
      payload: JSON.stringify(reqBody),
      muteHttpExceptions: true,
    };
    var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/" + encodeURIComponent(urlGiven) + "/searchAnalytics/query";
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    console.log(response);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I managed to make it work but your example is really great, my comprehension of the way of doing it is really much better now. I'm actualy trying to update this to use a service account instead (for my purpose) I guess i need to open up a new thread since it's not the same issue.

Comment: @LIMJacky With a service account is so much better, just edit your question and I'll post the solution.

Comment: @LIMJacky Updated the answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Morfinismo, i'll try it out right now !!

Comment: Ive tried the code but it does return me an error saying the access isn't granted or the token is expired. I've updated the thread in the same time, thanks for your help @Morfinismo.